# Unable to generate access token in facebook graph api explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a new app with type academic research. With this I have completed the verification process for Verify your Identity, Verify your relationship with an academic institution and Complete researcher profile.

However, the most basic flow to fetch data with @GET /v19 /me?fields=id,name API is not working and giving error: Feature Unavailable This feature is unavailable because this app is not approved for the public_profile permission.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any missing steps in the procedure ?